# Globalization issue on asp.net: it's not updating accentuated words

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls, globalization

I've created an website available in three languages: english, portuguese and spanish.

It's everything working fine except for one thing: it was not updating a BoundField when an accentuated word is loaded into it.

Below is the field which doesn't update in the gridview at MEMGridView.ascx:

```
<asp:BoundField  DataField="Ocupacao" HeaderText="Ocupação" SortExpression="Ocupação" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource9">
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

At `App_LocalResources` are three files with this values:

1. MEMGridView.ascx.resx (english is default) -
   BoundFieldResource9.HeaderText - "Fill Rate"
2. MEMGridView.ascx.pt-BR.resx - BoundFieldResource9.HeaderText -
   "Ocupação"
3. MEMGridView.ascx.es.resx - BoundFieldResource9.HeaderText -
   "Ocupación"

When the page loads for the first time it exhibits **"Fill Rate"**. Then I change the language to spanish and it exhibits **"Ocupación"**. If I return to load the page in english it updates all fields, except for the accentuated ones. So it continues to show **"Ocupación"** instead of **"Fill Rate"**.

I have no clues of what can be happening.

-- Update - Additional Info --

MEMGridView is a UserControl inside of DashBoard.aspx. Everytime someone changes the language value in ddlLanguage (dropdownlist) or clicks on Update button a postback is generated.

This is the MEMGridView event suposed to update the fields (actually, it updates all fields except the accentuated ones).

```
public partial class MEMGridView : UserControl
{
    ...

    protected override void FrameworkInitialize()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["ddlLanguage"]))
        {
            string str = Request["ddlLanguage"];

            //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(str);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(str);
        }
        else
        {
            string preferredLanguage;

            if (Request.QueryString["Language"] != null)
                preferredLanguage = Request.QueryString["Language"];
            else
                preferredLanguage = Request.UserLanguages[0];

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(preferredLanguage);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(preferredLanguage);
        }

        base.FrameworkInitialize();
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are using to change the Culture and UiCulture. Wich event are you using? Accents are not a problem for RESX files and asp.net Globalization.

Comment: @Phx Added some info. I faced this issue with accentuation only in the BoundField.

Comment: You are changing the culture from a userControl. You should do it on master page and it would change all the controls at the same time. No need to do it on a user control. Why you change the language from a UserControl? You need diferent languages on different controls?

Comment: @Phx No at all. I'll make a change based on what you said and see what happens.

Comment: Can you try to put that code on your Master page? Use this event: protected override void InitializeCulture()

Comment: Are you using asp.net 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encountered same problem. Fixed by replacing the BoundField with TemplateField, just like that:

```
<asp:TemplateField ...>
    <ItemTemplate><%# Eval( "Ocupacao" ) %></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: It really worked out. Thanks! (I'm sorry that took this long for me to respond. I had fixed this in an awkward way and left this problem behind. Now, with your help, I'll correct it in the proper way)

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to override the InitializeCulture from the Page (not MasterPage)?

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also, when you say you "return to load the page in english", how did you do that? Is that via browser navigation or Server.Transfer? If it's the latter, did you use:

`Server.Transfer(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, false);`﻿

Answer (score 0):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/what-is-globalization-and-localization-in-Asp-Net/

this link will help you

---

Text="<%$Resources:Resource,AccCode%>"

"<%$Resources:Your Main Resource file Name, Add Name Of Resource field which you want to display %>"

< asp:Label ID="lblresdisplay"   Font-Size="Large"   runat="server"                     Text="<%$Resources:Resource,AccCode%>">

< asp:Label ID="Label1" Font-Size="Large" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource,AccCode%>">

---

--protected override void InitializeCulture()

```
{

    base.InitializeCulture();

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new   System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Session["Culture"].ToString());

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Session["Culture"].ToString());



}
```

}